# How can I know how to insert a 2 x 1 page in a printer, for flipping on short edge?

Tags: printing

To save paper, I print 2 pages on one side in landscape mode, and read both sides by [flipping on the short edge](http://www.office.xerox.com/userdoc/P740/P740man/740.18.html).

[image]

Without trial-and-error (choosing one direction randomly, then printing the result), how can I most efficiently deduce which of the 4 possible positions is correct? [To wit](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=HO3871&locale=en&userlocale=EN_US):

[image]

Comment: Why would it matter? Is your paper 4-dimensional, or what changes when it is rotated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your brain cells for something important.

- Print two copies of side 1.
- Face one in the first orientation and label the left edge.  Face the other in the second orientation and label the left edge.
- Load them in the printer and print two copies of side 2.
- Look at the two results.  Save the correct one for reference, or make a note of which orientation to use.

Question answered, and no brain cells harmed in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Printers always* print a page's content from top to bottom. In other words, the edge of the paper that comes into contact with the printing mechanism *first* will become the top of the page.

The tricky part of using this information to answer your question is determining if the printer folds over the paper before printing on it. If it does not then your first graphic will be correct. If it does, then the second graphic is correct.

*This is based on having worked with many printers and never observing one print a page "bottom up."